# Failed to load android xml file

Tags: android, eclipse

I have installed latest version of eclipse, ADT and SDK but when i start new android application project in eclipse (Mars version) everytime i get following error.

"Failed to find the style corresponding to the id 2130772027".

I have tried related solutions like changing API to lower version and changing Theme but it does not work so can i get another solution.[image]

Given Below is my XML code :

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

android:layout_width="match_parent"

android:layout_height="match_parent"

android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"

android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"

android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"

android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"

tools:context="com.example.hii.MainActivity" >

<TextView

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:text="@string/hello_world" />
```

Comment: share your xml code.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have particular API level in your SDK manger as specified in the layout window. (API 23)

Add android namespace to your layout

Clean the project and run.

Comment: Same result, Anything else ?

Comment: I have solved this issue by installing lower version APIs. Thank you.

Comment: Please post how you solved the issue in steps, so that people who face same issue can able to get rid out of it easily. @Kajal

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse is no longer supported, go to the android studio.

https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html

Answer (score 0):

This is due to appcompat_v7 lib which is present in you package explorer you should create every project with minimum required sdk API 14 which is 4.0 icecream sandwich.